# Exporting Google Earth Engine dictionary to CSV

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am running a grouped reduction in GEE and need to export the resulting dictionary to a CSV. Here's the grouped reduction code:

```
// Grouped mean reducer 
var means = BIandEVT.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().group({
    groupField: 1,
    groupName: 'Value',
  }),
  //geometry: region.geometry(),
  geometry: all2018.geometry(), //fire areas
  scale: 1000,
  maxPixels: 1e8
});
```

It outputs a dictionary as such:

[image: Dictionary object containing a list called "groups" and 119 elements which each contain a "Value" and "mean"]

All I need to do is export the dictionary as a CSV (a text file could work as well). Ideally the CSV would have two columns -  "Value" and "mean". I've already tried sending to a list and sending to a feature class without much luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to turn your means into an `ee.FeatureCollection`:

```
var means = ee.FeatureCollection(
  ee.List(
    BIandEVT.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().group({
        groupField: 1,
        groupName: 'Value',
      }),
      geometry: all2018.geometry(), //fire areas
      scale: 1000,
      maxPixels: 1e8
    }).get('groups')
  ).map(function (properties) {
    return ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([0, 0]), properties)
  })
)

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: means, 
  selectors: ['Value', 'mean']
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/8e37983b8fa7429165a0498f70b2e81a